# Vim autocmd not working with nnoremap

Tags: vim

I am trying to setup vim for compiling and runing c and c++ programs right inside the editor, but these don't seem to work:

```
autocmd! filetype *.c        nnoremap <leader>cc :!gcc -o %:p:r %<cr>
autocmd! filetype *.c        nnoremap <leader>cr :!gcc -o %:p:r %<cr>:!%:p:r<cr>
autocmd! filetype *.cpp *.cc nnoremap <leader>cc :!g++ -o %:p:r %<cr>
autocmd! filetype *.cpp *.cc nnoremap <leader>cr :!g++ -o %:p:r %<cr>:!%:p:r<cr>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The FileType autocommand uses the filetype not the filename to match against. You can instead use c and cpp. See `:h FileType`. However your problems do not end there:

- These are global mappings. There for open up a c file and the mappings change. Open up a cpp file and the mappings change no matter what buffer you are in. Use `nnoremap <buffer>` instead. See `:h :map-local`
- Using `autocmd!` without a group. `autocmd!` will remove all previously defined and add in the current autocommand. It would be best to create a group with `augroup`.
- Optionally you can use `%<` instead of `%:r`.
- You may also want to look into pushing this into an ftplugin or after/ftplugin variant. `:h ftplugin` and `:h after-directory`

All together:

```
augroup CBuild
  autocmd!
  autocmd filetype c   nnoremap <buffer> <leader>cc :!gcc -o %:p:r %<cr>
  autocmd filetype c   nnoremap <buffer> <leader>cr :!gcc -o %:p:r %<cr>:!%:p:r<cr>
  autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <buffer> <leader>cc :!g++ -o %:p:r %<cr>
  autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <buffer> <leader>cr :!g++ -o %:p:r %<cr>:!%:p:r<cr>
augroup END
```

Comment: Thanks. Putting such things into the ftplugin dir will be desirable, but vim seems not to recognize cpp.vim, and when a cpp file is opened, it sources c.vim and ignores the former. Is there anyway to workaround this?

Comment: I have made a quick test and have no issues with creating an ftplugin `~/.vim/ftplugin/cpp.vim`. If you want to see what is sourced you can look at `:scriptnames`.

Answer (score 0):

I modified it this way and it worked:

```
autocmd! filetype c        nnoremap <leader>cc :!gcc -o %:p:r %<cr>
autocmd! filetype c        nnoremap <leader>cr :!gcc -o %:p:r %<cr>:!%:p:r<cr>
autocmd! filetype cpp      nnoremap <leader>cc :!g++ -o %:p:r %<cr>
autocmd! filetype cpp      nnoremap <leader>cr :!g++ -o %:p:r %<cr>:!%:p:r<cr>
```

Comment: ...for your limited understanding of "worked". See Peter Rincker's answer for the remaining issues with this.