# Is there a better way to map command call based on filetype

Tags: vim

I'm new to vim after switching from Notepad and Notepad++, but I've been using it exclusively for the past four months. In my .vimrc I have a command that automatically changes the command call based on file extensions. For example, if I'm editing an R file, I can press `<F5>` and vim executes `!Rscript %:p<cr>`, but if I switch to a python file and press `<F5>`, vim executes `!python %:p<cr>`. I accomplish this by putting the following in my .vimrc:

```
    autocmd BufRead *.R noremap <F5> :!Rscript %:p<cr>
    autocmd BufRead *.pl noremap <F5> :!perl %:p<cr>
    autocmd BufRead *.py noremap <F5> :!python %:p<cr>
```

I'm wondering if this is the "proper" vim way to execute it based on the command call. I know some of python files I work with do not have a *.py extension, and so the setting is useless in this case.

Comment: possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825032/vim-inoremap-for-specific-filetypes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085858/vim-autocmd-not-working-with-nnoremap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do 2 things:

- Create a mapping local to a specific buffer by using the `<buffer>` option for `noremap`.
- Load the mappings for just a specific filetype.

This can be done via an `autocmd` and `FileType` event in your `.vimrc` like so:

```
autocmd FileType perl noremap <buffer> <F5> :!perl %:p<cr>
```

The other way option is by creating a filetype plugin. (see `:h ftplugin` for more details)

A simple example is do create a file named, `~/.vim/ftplugin/perl.vim` and place your mappings inside like so:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :!perl %:p<cr>
```

I personally lean more towards the ftplugin approach but having a everything in your `.vimrc` file can be nice.

For more help see:

```
:h :au
:h FileType
:h map-local
:h ftplugin
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have `BufRead *.py`, the autocommand was trigger only when it is loading a `*.py` buffer/file.

vim has filetype detection mechanism.

> Vim can detect the type of file that is edited.  This is done by
>   checking the file name and sometimes by inspecting the contents of the
>   file for specific text.

you should switch `:filetype on`

and use `FileType` event in your autocmd.