# VIM: why do these bindings work only sometimes?

Tags: vim, key-bindings

I've got these bindings in my .vimrc. They work most of the time, but sometimes they don't: they will just save the file but not run it.

Then I go into insert mode and exit it back to normal mode, and they work again. What could be the problem?

Thanks!

```
autocmd FileType python map <C-k> :write <CR> :! python % <CR>
autocmd FileType lisp  map <C-k> :write <CR> :! clisp % <CR>
autocmd FileType scala  map <C-k> :write <CR> :! scala % <CR>
```

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/18846586/438329

Answer (score 4):

There are many topics to discuss here so with out further ado:

#### Mappings

Your current mappings `map <c-k> ...` will only work in normal, visual, and operator-pending modes. However executing your mappings in visual mode or operator-pending modes would save the buffer with only a range of lines (read not good). I suggest you make your mappings for normal mode only.

Two general rules of thumb:

- Always supply a mode like `n` for normal.
- Always use `noremp` instead of `map` unless you are mapping to a `<Plug>` mapping.

So one of your mappings might look something similar to this:

```
nnoremap <c-k> :w<cr>:!python %<cr>
```

For more information:

```
:h :map-modes
:h map-overview
:h :nore
:h map-listing
:h map-verbose
```

#### Filetype based mappings

You need to do 2 things:

- Create a mapping local to a specific buffer by using the `<buffer>` option for `noremap`.
- Load the mappings for just a specific filetype.

This can be done via an `autocmd` and `FileType` event in your `.vimrc` like so:

```
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <c-k> :w<cr>:!python %:p<cr>
```

The other way option is by creating a filetype plugin. (see `:h ftplugin` for more details)

A simple example is do create a file named, `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` and place your mappings inside like so:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <c-k> :w<cr>:!python %:p<cr>
```

I personally lean more towards the ftplugin approach but having a everything in your `.vimrc` file can be nice.

For more help see:

```
:h :au
:h FileType
:h map-local
:h ftplugin
```

#### `:make`

A more vim like way of doing this would be to use `:make`. (Assuming you want to lint vs execute your current buffer)

- `:make` will execute the `'makeprg'`. It defaults to `make` which is great of C projects
- After running `:make` the quickfix list will be contain any errors.
- Set your compiler via the `:compiler` command.
- Extra parameter can be passed like so `:make foo-command`
- Current filename can be represented by `%`. e.g. `:make %`

Often people set do `:complier`/`'makeprg'` in side of ftplugins e.g. `~/.vim/ftplugin/perl.vim` or `autocmd`'s e.g. `autocmd FileType perl compiler perl`.

Fop more help see:

```
:h :make
:h 'makeprg'
:h :compiler
:h c_%
```

#### quickfix list

- Use `:cnext` and `:cprev` to move between your errors.
- `:copen` to open up the quickfix list in a window (`:cclose` to close)
- `:cwindow` to open quickfix list window only if there are errors
- May want to use better mappings for `:cnext` and friends. I suggest Tim Pope's [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin

For more help see the following:

```
:h quickfix
:h :cnext
:h :cope
```

#### Alternatives to using `:make`

- Just use `<c-z>` to suspend vim and run your build system. (Cons: loose out on the quickfix list)
- Use `:!` to compile. (Same cons as suspending) e.g. `:!make`
- [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) is a syntax checking system that checks files on save
- [Ale](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) (Asynchronous Lint Engine) is a plugin for providing linting in NeoVim and Vim 8 while you edit your text files
- [Dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) can be used to run things in the background. Great for test suites
- May want to consider terminal multiplexers like [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) or [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).
- [SingleComplile](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3115) tries and takes some of the work out of using `:make`

#### Conclusion

Personally I would install [ALE](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) as this removes the need for your mappings. It is also a great idea to learn how to use the location (or quickfix) list. When you are ready to get your hands dirty then you can learn and use `:make`.

#### tl;dr

Install [ALE](https://github.com/w0rp/ale).

Answer (score 0):

The space inserted between `<CR>` and `:` could lead to errors, because this space is really entered during the execution of the mapping.

With `:noremap` or `:nnoremap` (which should be used most of the times, as Peter Rincker wrote in his answer), it wouldn't be a big problem, since it only would move the cursor one char to the right (see `:h <space>`).
But with `:map`, it could trigger a custom mapping (or a partial one).

Then, instead of:

```
autocmd FileType python map <C-k> :write <CR> :! python % <CR>
```

the following would be better:

```
autocmd FileType python map <C-k> :write <CR>:! python % <CR>
```

and this one, really better:

```
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <C-k> :write <CR>:! python % <CR>
```